# Ring theory (about prime ideal)

Tags: maximal-and-prime-ideals

How can we find the number of prime ideals of $Z_{10^5}$ ? It has been asked that the number of prime ideal of $Z_{10^5}$ is

$a) 2
$

$b) 5
$

$c) 10
$

$d) 10000$

Comment: Welcome to Math SX! Do you mean the ring $\mathbf Z/10^5\mathbf Z$?

Answer (score 3):

You just compute the number of prime ideals in $\mathbb{Z}$ containing $10^5\mathbb{Z}$. Since $a\mathbb{Z}\supseteq b\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $a\mid b$…